# Select dependiente en angular

Tags: angularjs

Buenas tardes.

Estoy aprendiendo angular y no se bien como trabajar con los select. Quiero tener dos select y que el segundo dependa del primero.

Por ejemplo:

```
select 1
<select> 
<option>Animales</option>
<option> Frutas</option>
</select>
```

En caso de seleccionar Frutas en el 1 select debe aparecer en el select 2 las frutas, caso contrario aparece los nombres de los animales pero no los dos tipos frutas y animales al mismo tiempo por eso digo que el 2 select depende del 1.

```
select 2
<select> 
<option>Perro</option>
<option>Gato</option>
</select>

<select> 
<option>Platano</option>
<option>Manzana</option>
</select>
```

Cuando haga click en el option1 y se muestre las dos opciones Animales y Frutas y seleccionar Frutas en el 2 option deberia aparecer la información relacionada con frutas Platano, Manzana.

También necesito saber como puedo poner un valor que aparezca por defecto en el `option`

Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas

Comment: como puedo hacerlo para angular 6?

Answer (score 3):

Solo debes tener en tu controlador 2 arreglos:

- tipos: contiene las opciones (Frutas, Animales, etc.).
- things: contiene las opciones de acuerdo al tipo seleccionado.

Para tener un valor por defecto, en este caso le he puesto *Seleccionar* como valor por defecto, tan solo debes ponerle el atributo `value` vacio.

**Ejemplo**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('selectController', ['$scope', ($scope) => {
    $scope.type = '';
    $scope.thing = '';
    $scope.types = ['Frutas', 'Animales'];
    $scope.things = [];
    
    $scope.putThings = function() {
      if($scope.type === 'Frutas') {
        $scope.things = ['Plátano', 'Manzana', 'Pera'];
      } else {
        $scope.things = ['Perro', 'Gato', 'Conejo'];
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ejemplo de selects con AngulaJS</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="selectController">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
   <!-- tipos -->
   <select ng-model="type" ng-change="putThings()">
     <option value="" selected>Seleccionar</option>
     <option ng-repeat="t in types">{{t}}</option>
   </select>
   <!-- depende del select -->
   <select ng-model="thing">
     <option value="" selected>Seleccionar</option>
     <option ng-repeat="t in things">{{t}}</option>
   </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias alternativas para realizar el comportamiento que indicas. Entre las dos que más relevantes pueden ser, están las siguientes:

- Utilizar la directiva ng-change para asignar una acción al momento de que cambia el valor del primer select.
- Utilizar $watch para ver cuándo cambia el valor del primer select.

Además, va a depender de cómo estás mostrando las opciones de los selects que tienes. Puedes utilizar también dos alternativas:

- Uso de la directiva ng-options
- Uso de ng-repeat para generar options

Por ejemplo, con la directiva ng-change, podría ser así (asumiendo que el primer select tiene como **ng-model="select1"** y el segundo select tiene como **ng-model="select2"**).

```
<select ... ng-model="select1" ng-change="selectChanged()" ng-options="opt.value as opt.label for opt in options"></select>
<select ... ng-model="select2" ng-options="dep.value as dep.label for dep in deps"></select>
```

Y en el controlador:

```
...
$scope.options = [{value:0,label:'Animales'}, {value:1,label:'Frutas'}];
$scope.deps = [];
var animals = [{value:0,label:'Perro',}, {value:1,label:'Gato'}];
var fruits = [{value:0,label:'Platano'}, {value:1,label:'Manzana'}];
var arrays = [animals, fruits];
...
$scope.selectChanged = function() {
  $scope.deps = arrays[$scope.select1];
}
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo en un artículo que he encontrado en la siguiente página:

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/consultorio-desarrollo-web/

Answer (score 0):

El código que necesitas es muy simple, sólo usa `ng-if` para mostrar/ocultar los `select` dependientes. No necesitas escribir nada de código para esto.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tipos = ['Animales', 'Frutas'];

    $scope.animales = ['Perro', 'Gato'];

    $scope.frutas = ['Platano', 'Manzana'];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="SelectCtrl">
  <p>
    <select ng-model="tipo" ng-options="tipo for tipo in  tipos">
    </select>
  </p>
  <p ng-if="tipo === 'Animales'">
    <select ng-model="seleccion" ng-options="animal for animal in animales">
    </select>
  </p>

  <p ng-if="tipo === 'Frutas'">
    <select ng-model="seleccion" ng-options="fruta for fruta in frutas">
    </select>
  </p>
</div>
```

Puedes usar `ng-show` en lugar de `ng-if` pero ten cuidado si en tu lógica tienes alguna validación como `required` o `ng-required`, el select estará oculto y no podrás hacerle submit al formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el `ng-switch` y no requiere usar una lista en el **controlador** como indican mas que un `$scope.opcion`.

```
      select 1
      <select ng-model="opcion"> 
         <option value="Animales">Animales</option>
         <option value="Frutas"> Frutas</option>
      </select> 

      <div ng-switch="opcion">
         <div ng-switch-when="Animales">
            <select> 
              <option>Perro</option>
              <option>Gato</option>
            </select>
         </div>
         <div ng-switch-when="Frutas">
            <select> 
               <option>Platano</option>
               <option>Manzana</option>
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos...